# Как перенести переменную perimeter из метода getPerimeter() в getSquare() Java?

Tags: java

public class Triangle {

```
Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {

    this.sideA = sideA;
    this.sideB = sideB;
    this.sideC = sideC;
}

double sideA; 
double sideB; 
double sideC; 


double getPerimeter() {
    double perimeter = this.sideA + this.sideB + this.sideC;
    return perimeter;

}


double getSquare () {
    double perimeter = this.sideA + this.sideB + this.sideC;
    double square =
            Math.sqrt( perimeter/2 ) *
            Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideA) *
            Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideB) *
            Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideA);




    return square;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);
    System.out.println("Area of the triangle is " + triangle1.getSquare()); 
    System.out.println("Perimeter of the triangle is " + triangle1.getPerimeter()); 

}
```

}

Comment: doible perimeter = getPerimeter()

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Triangle {
Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
this.sideA = sideA;
this.sideB = sideB;
this.sideC = sideC;
}
double sideA; 
double sideB; 
double sideC; 
double getPerimeter() {
double perimeter = this.sideA + this.sideB + this.sideC;
return perimeter;
}
double getSquare () {
double perimeter = this.sideA + this.sideB + this.sideC;
double square =
        Math.sqrt( perimeter/2 ) *
        Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideA) *
        Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideB) *
        Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideA);
return square;
}
double getSquare2() {
double perimeter = getPerimeter();
double square =
        Math.sqrt( perimeter/2 ) *
        Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideA) *
        Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideB) *
        Math.sqrt((perimeter/2) - this.sideA);
return square;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);
System.out.println("Area of the triangle is " + triangle1.getSquare());
System.out.println("Area of the triangle is " + triangle1.getSquare2());
System.out.println("Perimeter of the triangle is " + triangle1.getPerimeter()); 
}
}
```